# SQL like with multiple textboxes

Tags: sql, vb.net, select

For my company I have to create a customer database, which I manage over a VB.NET application.

The application has a few textboxes and a button to "Search" for a customer. If I type in the name of a customer the SQL Select statement is working and populating my datagrid.

But I want to be able to type in the name of the customer AND the street where he lives in. What is the best solution for this? using cases? using a  lot of If statements?

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)      Handles Button1.Click
    If True Then
        Dim Conn As New MySqlConnection
        Dim da As MySqlDataAdapter
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim plz As String = plzTextBox.Text

        Conn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;uid=root;pwd=;database=wws; "

        Dim sql As String = String.Empty
        If vornameTextBox.Text <> String.Empty Then
            sql = "vorname = " & vornameTextBox.Text.Trim
        End If
        If nachnameTextBox.Text <> String.Empty Then
            AddCondition(sql, "nachname LIKE '%" & nachnameTextBox.Text.Trim & "%'")
        End If
        If emailTextBox.Text <> String.Empty Then
            AddCondition(sql, "email LIKE '%" & emailTextBox.Text.Trim & "%'")
        End If
        If plzTextBox.Text <> String.Empty Then
            AddCondition(sql, "plz LIKE '%" & plzTextBox.Text.Trim & "%'")
        End If
        If sql <> String.Empty Then
            da = New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT id,vorname,nachname,email,plz,strasse,nummer,stiege,stock,tuer FROM kunden WHERE " + sql, Conn)

            da.Fill(dt)

            DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
        End If



    Else
        DataGridView1.ColumnCount = 1
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add("1")

    End If

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your are open for [sql-injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953(v=sql.105).aspx). Use [`SqlParameter`s](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqlparameter.html).

Comment: Thanks for the hint, will replace it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid using lots of if statements if you really want, but all you're doing is shunting a load onto your SQL server instead of having it on the client.

The example here is one where you can use lots of if statements or ternary operators to determine how you build your SQL statement, putting a very light processing load on the client, or you can just insert the text value of each of your fields, followed by a percentage sign and surrounded by single quotes, thus making your SQL server evaluate the contents of those fields when it otherwise wouldn't if the field is blank.

It's possible query plan optimization would remove those superfluous field searches, and maybe it wouldn't.  I'm typing this on my phone and so don't have anything available to test with.